# "invalid character '\x00' after top-level value"

Tags: json, go

I am getting this error while unmarshalling json in a for loop.
The first time through the loop is unmarshalling fine but on the next iteration I am getting this error.

I am new to golang and this error message is not clear. Can someone please explain in what cases this error occurs and how I am supposed to avoid it.

Comment: Post some code please.

Comment: You have two backslashes in your title. Did the error message really say `'\\x00'` or just `'\x00'`?

Comment: No it has only one, like this: [invalid character '\x00' after top-level value]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Thank you for answering my question.

This error came due to incorrect json before that there is little more story to this,

I have a field **detail** of type json.RawMessage I have SELECT query where I am trying to read json from the table and scan to **detail** and appending it to the struct.

After for loop ends when I look at **detail** JSON it got same record multiple times with and without end braces. After giving it so much thinking I figured casting detail with byte helped.

Eg: instead of just rows.Scan(&detail) try this:
rows.Scan((*[]byte)(&detail)) solved the above problem

Comment: Good feedback, more precise than my answer. +1

Answer (score 28):

Looking at the source code of [`encoding/json/scanner.go`](http://golang.org/src/pkg/encoding/json/scanner.go)

```
// stateEndTop is the state after finishing the top-level value,
// such as after reading `{}` or `[1,2,3]`.
// Only space characters should be seen now.
func stateEndTop(s *scanner, c int) int {
    if c != ' ' && c != '\t' && c != '\r' && c != '\n' {
        // Complain about non-space byte on next call.
        s.error(c, "after top-level value")
    }
    return scanEnd
}
```

So check how your JSON string ends.

For example, in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/77HJlZhWXpk), to illustrate a potential issue:

> `ReadFromUDP` can return a packet of any size, from 1 to 2000 bytes, you need to reslice your buffer using the number of bytes actually read.

```
json.Unmarshal(buf[:n], &msg)
```

Same in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/golang-nuts/77HJlZhWXpk/nyL4XKlnTkUJ):

```
request := make([]byte, 1024)
read_len, err := conn.Read(request)
request_right := request[:read_len]
j := new(Json)
err := j.UnmarshalJSON(request) // not working
```

> if `read_len < len(request)` then request will contain extra "`\x00`" at the end
>   and that's why `UnmarshalJSON(request)` won't work.