# swift vs objc JSON encoding

Tags: objective-c, swift, gomobile

I am using a GOlang library with mobile bindings. One of the models from GO library takes a data as a parameter. If should be utf8 encoded JSON string. When I am encoding that JSON in objc everything works fine but I cannot instantiate that model with JSON encoded in swift. What can cause that?

here is objc code:

```objectivec
NSString *invitation = @"{ \"@id\": \"242304ff-7028-4991-b56e-842a85f345dd\", \"recipientKeys\": [ \"EXrC5FVVBVxRf2DZ8g638d5BA9fzNQNbLFQFXn8nzQHL\" ], \"serviceEndpoint\": \"ws://aws.xsx.com:8002\"}";
NSData *data = [invitation dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

I've tried this in swift but doesn't work:

```swift
let data = """
{
    "serviceEndpoint": "ws://aws.xsx.com:8002",
    "recipientKeys": [
        "2VPFQH6kBRJbtve3xmpVbLbh7YqfiB9gE8mHr8rbmznS"
    ],
    "@id": "503509ff-4014-41f6-a43b-6eb6e7d5141d"
}
""".data(using: .utf8)
```

and I've also tried to encode that JSON using JSONEncoder

`let data = try! JSONEncoder().encode(invitation)` where invitation is `Codable` struct:

```swift
struct Invitation: Codable {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case serviceEndpoint = "serviceEndpoint"
        case recipientKeys = "recipientKeys"
        case id = "@id"
    }
    let serviceEndpoint: String
    let recipientKeys: [String]
    let id: String
}
```

I am always getting that error:

> invalid character '\x00' looking for beginning of value

Comment: If you are encoding a struct why not include that struct in your question

Comment: @JoakimDanielson good point

Comment: Encoding the struct with the values you have supplied works fine for me, I assume you have some invisible character somewhere in your json

Comment: Enter your json [here](https://app.quicktype.io/) and it will give you the correct structs and decoding code.

Comment: And maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25187718/invalid-character-x00-after-top-level-value) is helpful.

Comment: Is the extra comma after the `@id` line before the `}` allowed?